# PHP thinks my string is also an associative array. Thinks array is string. Trying to extract a CSRF Token from it

Tags: php, arrays, string, security

I'm currently rewriting a CSRF Token verification function for a client. They have this odd system where ALL of the session information for a user is saved to an sql database field as a string.

`$D = {'email' => 'TheDude@company.com','userid' => 69,'uid' => 69,'scanstatus' => 'S','CSRFToken' => 'tokenGENexample==','_SESSION_ATIME' => 1643289149,'abbr' => 'TheDude','scantype' => 0,'_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR' => 'IP Address','_SESSION_CTIME' => 1643282918,'scanexpiration' => 1643289447,'_SESSION_ETIME' => 1800,'_SESSION_ID' => 'sessionGENexample','scanmode' => 100};;$D`

It is stored exactly how you I pasted it.

Then, this verification function uses `str_replace` to turn it into a line of code that assigns `$D` to an array:

`$D = array('email' => 'TheDude@company.com','userid' => 69,'uid' => 69,'scanstatus' => 'S','CSRFToken' => 'tokenGENexample==','_SESSION_ATIME' => 1643289149,'abbr' => 'TheDude','scantype' => 0,'_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR' => 'IP Address','_SESSION_CTIME' => 1643282918,'scanexpiration' => 1643289447,'_SESSION_ETIME' => 1800,'_SESSION_ID' => 'sessionGENexample','scanmode' => 100);`

It then runs this in an `eval()` function, and needless to say, is a security risk. I don't even feel like its wise to hold that much sensitive information in a single field, but I digress.

`$D` is then passed back to our main CSFR Token function, it checks for the data associated with 'CSRFToken' and goes along its merry way.

My idea to removed the `eval()` was this, and please let me know if this is a terrible idea:
Take the string, parse it for JUST the `tokenGENexample==`, assign that string directly to $D, and then just rewrite our main CSRF function to look for a value, rather than the associative array value.

To do so, I was exploring a few sub ideas, and that's where I ran into this weird PHP error that I'm asking about right now. Sorry for taking a while to get to the point, but I needed assistance with the parser too, and figured I'd add context.

I decided to use `parse_str()` **BEFORE** `str_replace()` is called, to see if it would spit out all of the values to an output.

My log spit this out: `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion...`

Well how the heck is it being read as an array, if its clearly still just a string?

Alright, if it wants to be an array, I figured I'd use `array_values()` to spit me out my values I need.

Welp, then it spits out this warning `PHP Warning:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array...`

Now I'm at a loss. It thinks a string is in array, and an array is a string. I think it has to do with it being an associative array.

I went down this huge rabbit hole, simply because the client has some old unsafe code that would run an `eval()` function to make `$D` equal that array.

Kind fellows of Stackoverflow, I'm at a darn loss here. Does PHP have built in functions I can use to JUST get the CSRF token out of this string (or convert it to an array?) and assign it `$D` without that goofy `eval()` call?

Comment: What do you want with `parse_str`, for that kind of data? That function is for data in a query string format - `param1=value1&param2=value2&...`

Comment: Why oh why would one, of all possible options, serialize with [var_export()](https://www.php.net/var_export) and then mangle it up a bit? What's the function of the `$D` anyway, why not E or X or ... not necessary!? Seriously, I'd just batch convert the lot into JSON, or `serialize()`, or something, that can be unserialized without `eval`. If you stored it as JSON, you could also query its values if you're running a modern MySQL version.

Comment: You could always regex that into JSON and use `json_decode()`... hoping that there are no edge cases that would result in invalid JSON.

Comment: I didn't write this ancient mess, so please forgive me. I'm just trying to fix it, and I don't have the experience to do it myself in a safe and efficient way.

Comment: Well I wrote you a fix in a random act of kindness. ^_^

Comment: On your question, _Well how the heck is it being read as an array, if its clearly still just a string?_, You must have been doing something funny with `parse_str()` (which isn't the tool for this anyway) to get that error. It _is_ very much a string, however the_$result_ from `parse_str` will be an array (albeit in this case with just one key).

Answer (score 1):

Why oh why would one serialize with `var_export()` and then mangle it up a bit? And then back-mangle and use `eval()` to get the data back? I'd recommend batch-converting the lot into JSON, or `serialize()`, or any other format that can be unserialized without `eval()`. If you stored it as JSON, you could also query its values if you're running a modern MySQL version.

Now the serialization you have there isn't *too far* from valid JSON as it is, and can be regexed to conform... I emphasize, *this is not best or even good practice!*. However if it's for a one-off job, woe is the things we do to get the job done, and moving onward. Here's a "parser":

```
$str = <<<'DUH'
{'email' => 'TheDude@company.com','userid' => 69,'uid' => 69,'scanstatus' => 'S','CSRFToken' => 'tokenGENexample==','_SESSION_ATIME' => 1643289149,'abbr' => 'TheDude','scantype' => 0,'_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR' => 'IP Address','_SESSION_CTIME' => 1643282918,'scanexpiration' => 1643289447,'_SESSION_ETIME' => 1800,'_SESSION_ID' => 'sessionGENexample','scanmode' => 100};;$D
DUH;

// Fix ' -quoted keys and values:
$str = preg_replace("~'([^']+)'~", '"\1"', $str);

// Convert => to :
$str = str_replace(' => ', ':', $str);

// Trim the tail:
$str = preg_replace('~;;.+$~', '', $str);

$data = json_decode($str, true);
```

That could probably be more elegant. This results in:

```
array(14) {
    ["email"] · string(19) "TheDude@company.com"
    ["userid"] · int(69)
    ["uid"] · int(69)
    ["scanstatus"] · string(1) "S"
    ["CSRFToken"] · string(17) "tokenGENexample=="
    ["_SESSION_ATIME"] · int(1643289149)
    ["abbr"] · string(7) "TheDude"
    ["scantype"] · int(0)
    ["_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR"] · string(10) "IP Address"
    ["_SESSION_CTIME"] · int(1643282918)
    ["scanexpiration"] · int(1643289447)
    ["_SESSION_ETIME"] · int(1800)
    ["_SESSION_ID"] · string(17) "sessionGENexample"
    ["scanmode"] · int(100)
}
```

Which is a valid PHP array without resorting to `evil()`. N.B. This will break if you have escaped `\'` inside keys/values. Need a negative lookbehind for `\` before `'` if that's the case. If you have `'abbr' => 'O\'Dude'`, for example. At any rate, it's a good idea to fetch all of the serialized sessions and test to see whether everything parses gracefully.

Good practice: Don't throw this in as a permanent feature. Use it to convert the serialization into coherent data and store it in a more sensible format.

Comment: Markus, I can't thank you enough for the help this afternoon. I have learned a ton of useful information with what you've shared, and this ancient code continues to groan into action for another day lol
I actually have a follow up question regarding `preg_replace()` that I think would perhaps help some other wandering noobs such as myself. How could I only replace the first instance of a specified string or character?
Say I want to replace the first instance of 'e' with white space in your example string, would the code look something like this: `$str = preg_replace('e', ' ', $str, 1);` ?

Comment: Sure thing, glad it helped. On your regex question, only one way to find out for reals: trying it. `C:\php>php -a`, enter `Interactive shell`, type `php > echo preg_replace('~e~', '!', 'what eeeee more e and eee', 1);`, see `what !eeee more e and eee`. Seems that way. Testing things out leads to insight. Especially testing exotic things in production environment.